# Best way to sort data

Tags: java, android, sql, arrays, sorting

In my **Android** application I have to fill an **arraylist** object with the data taken from a **database**. Also the data should be sorted. So i have two ways.

1. Sort the data while taking from the database using **SQL** and put into array
2. Get data from database and put them into the **array** and sorl the data later

out of these which is more **efficient** and less affecting the **runtime**. Need some help. Thank you!

Comment: I'd expect it to be in SQL, given that the database engine is designed for exactly that sort of task, but I have no proof.

Comment: My Vote goes to 1st Option

Comment: mine also for 1st option

Comment: Sorting in sql is faster and efficient. However, you have to evaluate whether it fits our requirement. If not, you will have to implement a comparable interface for your object(if they are complex. for custom sort on objects) and get the work done. Or you perform sorting on both the sides, so that some load would be shared and the partially sorted rows could be further sorted in the java code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Sort the data while taking from the database using SQL and put into
>   array

If you are able to sort data on database level, do it. Sorting on database level is much more faster as in memory - especially if your memory is limitated in the case of many records.
Also performance can be increased by an usage of indexes which provide many databases.

So if you can and are able to sort in database, sort in database. If not, sort in application but here you are limitated by memory and sorting is significantly slower.

**Note:** It's worth to mention that if your sorting algorithm is very changeble during runtime (with high frequency and begins changing after data are retrieved from database) it's good approach to think about sorting in application and not in database and make some
 analysis focused on advantages and disadvatages due to application requirements (performance for instance).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on many things. But for general cases sorting from database is better as it may use indexings internally.

Answer (score 1):

Databases are built for retreivng data in a certain order so if you have a choice, use the database to sort.

If, however, your sorting requirements are complex and difficult to encode in the database language then you should do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If your dataset is small, then you can sort the data programmatically as you can do complex sort.

But if your data set is large, then DB sort is the best way to do. In my opinion its better to go with DB sort. Look at `ORDER BY` in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sorting using some simple logic then it is better to sort while taking from database. If it is complex logic then Java side sorting is better option.